# Как получить logcat удаленно?

Tags: java, android

Скажите пожалуйста есть ли средство какое - нибудь чтобы получать логи, такие же как в LogCat.

Я использую Fabric но он не все логи высылает. И как то криво. Тобишь не та строчка коорая вызвала ошибку, а тот момент когда краш произошел.

Короче я в LogCat вижу инфу куда более полезную чем в Fabric. Поэтому есть ли сервис для получения Logов всего приложения. Конечно если есть приложение которое показывает ошибки в самом телефоне тоже было бы не плохо. Главное чтобы я получил все ошибки.

logcat качяал из Google play но он требует Root права, у меня их нет. Firebase не подходит, он еще хуже fabric. Ошибки приходят через 10-15 минут, да и  не понятно на сайте где новые где старые. Короче ужас.

Если знаете что нибудь дельное посоветуйте пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Для чего вам все логи? Их может быть ооочень много, на некоторых устройствах, которые пишут в лог кат всё подряд. В фабрик вы сами можете добавить какие то необходимые данные в отчёт, который получите при краше приложения. [EnhancedReports](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html)

Comment: Я имел ввиду все ошибки связанные с текущим приложением.

Просто fabric не правильно как то работает, да и ждать 10 минут чтобы краш появился на сайте это не для меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет. Если вас интересует получение стека ошибок, то используйте acra
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Comment: +1, это действительно наилучшая библиотека для отлова логов

Comment: Fabric также прекрасно справляется с отловом ошибок. Автор вопроса хочет все логи получать.

Comment: @eugeneek, Еще раз Fabric не подходит. Я тестирую удаленно и мне надо логи видеть сразу, а не спустя 10 - 15 минут. А некоторые No crashes вообще не видно в Fabric.

Comment: @eugeneek, Смотрите. Вот есть допустим ошибка MediaPlayer. Fabric его не перешелт в логи. Вот я хочу найти такую вещь которая все логи скидывала куда нибудь. Пусть даже это будет apk приложение. Fabric так разве может?

Comment: Если ошибка вызывает краш приложения, то лог автоматом отправляется. Если это просто error, то вы можете вручную добавить стектрейс в фабрик и вызвать краш, который всё отправит на сервер.